# dl_iterate_phdr returns empty image-name on first entry

Tags: linux, glibc

I've developed this little C++ program for Linux

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <link.h>
#include <climits>
#include <dlfcn.h>

using namespace std;

template<typename Fn>
    requires requires( Fn fn, dl_phdr_info *image, size_t n ) { { fn( image, n ) } -> same_as<int>; } 
int dlIteratePhdr( Fn &&fn )
{
    return dl_iterate_phdr(
        []( dl_phdr_info *image, size_t size, void *pFn ) -> int
        {
            return (*(Fn *)pFn)( image, size );
        }, &fn );
};

int main()
{
    size_t nImages = 0;
    dlIteratePhdr( [&]( dl_phdr_info *, size_t ) -> int { ++nImages; return 0; } );
    vector<string> images;
    images.reserve( nImages );
    if( dlIteratePhdr(
        [&]( dl_phdr_info *image, size_t ) -> int
        {
            try
            {
                images.emplace_back( image->dlpi_name );
                return 0;
            }
            catch( ... )
            {
                return 1;
            }
        } ) )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    for( string const &image : images )
        cout << "\"" << image << "\"" << endl;
}
```

For my Ubuntu machine this prints:

```
""
"linux-vdso.so.1"
"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6"
"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1"
"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6"
"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6"
"/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
```

Why is the name of the first image empty ?
Is this reserved for the executable itself ?
And is it really necessary to copy the information given to the callback or would this be alive after dl_iterate_phdr ?

Comment: The empty name for the main program is [documented in the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html). As for keeping a pointer to any of it, it isn't something you own outside of the callback, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html#NOTES
"The first object visited by callback is the main program.  For the main program, the dlpi_name field will be an empty string."

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the name of the first image empty ?

Because the name of the main executable is not known to the loader.

Unlike the shared libraries, which are `mmap`ed by the loader, the main executable is mapped by the kernel itself, and only the file descriptor is passed in to the loader.

As Hasturkun commented, this behavior is [documented](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html) in the man page.

> Is this reserved for the executable itself ?

Yes.

> And is it really necessary to copy the information ...

The `dl_phdr_info` that is passed in is stack-allocated, and will get overwritten after each step (in fact, it's the *same* pointer every time; but this is an implementation detail).

The strings pointed by `dlpi_name` are dynamically allocated by the loader.

Strings corresponding to the libraries loaded during executable startup are likely to persist throughout the lifetime of the process, but strings corresponding to `dlopen()`ed libraries may get `free()`d on `dlclose()`. This is also an implementation detail and you are better off not relying on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to determine the executable path also, here's the above program which also does that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <link.h>
#include <climits>
#include <dlfcn.h>

using namespace std;

template<typename Fn>
    requires requires( Fn fn, dl_phdr_info *image, size_t n ) { { fn( image, n ) } -> same_as<int>; } 
int dlIteratePhdr( Fn fn )
{
    return dl_iterate_phdr(
        []( dl_phdr_info *image, size_t size, void *pFn ) -> int
        {
            return (*(Fn *)pFn)( image, size );
        }, &fn );
};

int main()
{
    size_t nImages = 0;
    dlIteratePhdr( [&]( dl_phdr_info *, size_t ) -> int { ++nImages; return 0; } );
    vector<string> images;
    images.reserve( nImages );
    if( dlIteratePhdr(
        [&]( dl_phdr_info *image, size_t ) -> int
        {
            try
            {
                if( *image->dlpi_name )
                    images.emplace_back( image->dlpi_name );
                else
                {
                    Dl_info dlInfo;
                    if( !dladdr( (void *)image->dlpi_addr, &dlInfo ) )
                        return 1;
                    char exePath[PATH_MAX];
                    if( !realpath( dlInfo.dli_fname, exePath ) )
                        return 1;
                    images.emplace_back( exePath );
                }
                return 0;
            }
            catch( bad_alloc const & )
            {
                return 1;
            }
        } ) )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    for( string const &image : images )
        cout << "\"" << image << "\"" << endl;
}
```

I don't know why the dl_iterate_phdr doesn't supply that path by itself if I can manage to get it otherwise.

Comment: "I don't know why" -- see the other answer. You get "a name", not necessarily "the name". It's also unreliable (try to `unlink(argv[0])` before invoking `dladdr`).